# Python import one subpackage without others

Tags: python, package, python-import, python-module

I have the following package structure

```
package
    __init__.py
    sub1
        __init__.py
        foo.py      # Contains class Foo
    sub2
        __init__.py
        bar.py      # Contains class Bar
```

I want to be able to just `import package` and have `package.Foo` and `package.Bar`, i.e. I want to have the subpackages be transparent to users.

The catch is that importing sub2 takes a long time, and many users don't care at all about the stuff in sub2 and only want the stuff in sub1.  Thus I want users to be able to say `import package.sub1` or `from package import sub1` to **just** import sub1 and skip the import of sub2.

I know I can achieve the first part by having `package/__init__.py` contain

```
from .sub1 import *
from .sub2 import *
```

and having `package/sub1/__init__.py` be `from .foo import Foo` and similarly for sub2.  However, this will always import sub1 and sub2 even if the user tries to import only `package.sub1`.

Correspondingly, I can achieve the second part by having `package/__init__.py` be empty and using the same `sub1/__init__.py` as above.  However, then just saying `import package` doesn't load sub1 or sub2, so users would have to explicitly load them and then refer to `package.sub1.Foo`.

Ideally a solution would work both in 2.7.10 and 3.5.0, but I'll accept one or the other if both isn't possible.

Comment: a better question is why do you have a long-running code at the module level in `sub2`

Comment: So, in fact, your question is: "I want `import package.sub1` to do strictly fewer things than just `import package`, right? Absent some weird hack like reading the bytecode in advance, i think it's not possible. `import A.B` must `import A` first. Note at the bottom of https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/importlib.html (last code block, line 15), `import_module` is a recursive function. However, you can easily have a third subpackage, `package.everything`, which will really import `sub1` and `sub2` into the same namespace.

Comment: @Veky: That is indeed exactly what I ended up doing (well, `package.all`, but close enough)

Comment: .all was my first idea, but I decided against it, since it a) evokes false association with `package.__all__`, and b) is a bit too short for something you don't want to encourage people to do (an attractive nuisance).

Answer (score 4):

The [`LazyLoader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.util.LazyLoader) class is provided for exactly this kind of situation: postponing loading of the module when it is actually used, instead of at the point of importing it.

To build a lazy loader you can follow the example in the documentation:

```
suffixes = importlib.machinery.SOURCE_SUFFIXES
loader = importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader
lazy_loader = importlib.util.LazyLoader.factory(loader)
finder = importlib.machinery.FileFinder(path, [(lazy_loader, suffixes)])
```

then you can use [`finder.find_spec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.abc.PathEntryFinder.find_spec) to obtain the spec of a module and pass the result to [`Loader.create_module`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.abc.Loader.create_module) to load it.

This is a bit cumbersome to do manually for just one module.

Note that searching for "lazy import python" you'll find quite a few solutions that have different pro and cons, some of which run in python2.x. However the `LazyLoader` class above is the official way of doing it in python3.5+

Comment: I can't get this to actually load the stuff from the subpackage.

If `sub2/__init__.py` has `from .bar import Bar`, it returns `ImportError: No module named 'package.bar'`

If it uses an absolute import, I get `ValueError: module object for 'package.sub2' substituted in sys.modules during a lazy load`

It also seems like this will just have the symbols under sub2, so I'd still have to say `package.sub2.Bar` rather than just `package.Bar`

Comment: For anyone looking at this in the future, if you (like me) can't get lazy loader to work, my solution was to just have a `package.all` (or .everything if you prefer) that imports everything, and the top level package doesn't import anything.  See the comments on the question for more discussion

Answer (score 0):

you could add your shortcuts to the `__init__.py` of your module:

**package/__init__.py**

```
__all__ = [
    ... add everything you want to be listed for this module
    'Foo',
    'Bar',
    ...
]
from package.sub1.foo import Foo
from package.sub2.bar import Bar
```

now you should be able to call:

```
from package import Bar
```

Comment: this enables `package.Bar` after `import package` but it doesn't handle the "lazy import" part of the question.